# Is it Possible to put Service inside CanvasWatchFaceService?

Tags: android, wear-os

How and where I can put my service inside canvasWatchfaceservice ?? my service is about httpurlconnection connect with server sends post request and the response is picture so I want to do this service in android wear ( wallpaper changer app ) is there a way or not and if there is a way  where should i put my service code ( I don't want codes just where to put my codes) and another question if my app workes on device and changes the wallpaper randomly can I pair it with my watch ( when device wallpaper changes the watch wallpaper changes too) or should i create a class and a button and intent it (because i tried that and not working)

myasyncTask

```
private class WallpaperData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://555.555.555.555/yay/yay.php");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write("method=get_random_wallpaper".getBytes());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
                Log.d("hey", buffer.toString());

            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            return forecastJsonStr;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);

            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String forecastJsonStr) {

        txt.setText(forecastJsonStr);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    Bitmap result = Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                            .load(hostName + hostWallpaperName + forecastJsonStr)
                            .get();
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();

        super.onPostExecute(forecastJsonStr);


    }
```

Comment: why do you need another service? you can start a Thread or AsyncTask in canvasWatchfaceservice to perform network operations. Yes you can trigger wallpaper change from handled (e.g. using Message API).

Comment: yes your right but can I write AsyncTask inside handled ..!?

Comment: and I need another service to activate when the device is rebooted

Comment: CanvasWatchfaceService runs while you have your watchface running. So if it is on, you can schedule wallpaper download using Handler or AlarmManager.

Comment: ok i get it but as i was asking where should i wrote my code(asynctask) ?? inside which override method or ..... maybe new class ?

Comment: In this case you need to provide some code, and some details on how handled connected to wear

Comment: check edited code